# SELinux policy for ifplugd and udev in Raspbian

Tags: selinux

I've recently enabled SELinux on my RaspberryPi and recieved some AVCs denials.

I'm reading SEL documentation and have resolved a few of them. But I'm not sure if I did it right. So please review my decision.

AVC:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1441426438.990:26): avc:  denied { read write } for  pid=2176
 comm="ifplugd" name="ifplugd.eth0.pid" dev="tmpfs" ino=6593
 scontext=system_u:system_r:ifplugd_t:s0
 tcontext=system_u:object_r:udev_var_run_t:s0
 tclass=file permissive=1
type=AVC msg=audit(1441426438.990:27): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=2176
 comm="ifplugd" path="/run/ifplugd.eth0.pid" dev="tmpfs" ino=6593
 scontext=system_u:system_r:ifplugd_t:s0
 tcontext=system_u:object_r:udev_var_run_t:s0
 tclass=file permissive=1
type=AVC msg=audit(1441426438.990:28): avc:  denied  { lock } for  pid=2176
 comm="ifplugd" path="/run/ifplugd.eth0.pid" dev="tmpfs" ino=6593
 scontext=system_u:system_r:ifplugd_t:s0
 tcontext=system_u:object_r:udev_var_run_t:s0
 tclass=file permissive=1
type=AVC msg=audit(1441426438.990:29): avc:  denied  { signull } for  pid=2176
 comm="ifplugd"
 scontext=system_u:system_r:ifplugd_t:s0
 tcontext=system_u:system_r:udev_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
 tclass=process permissive=1
```

While system boot up, **udev** executes script **/lib/udev/ifplugd.agent** where it starts **ifplugd** deamon.
When **ifplugd** starts, it creates files **/var/run/ifplugd.*interface*.pid** (**/var/run** is a symlink to **/run**). But the script **/lib/udev/ifplugd.agent** is running in **udev_t** SEL domain. So the resulting file have wrong context:

```
$ ls -lZ /run/ifplugd.eth0.pid
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root system_u:object_r:udev_var_run_t:s0 5 Sep  5 07:13 /run/ifplugd.eth0.pid
```

The right context should be:
**system_u:object_r:ifplugd_var_run_t:s0**

I've decided that **udev** should have permission for domain transition when it runs **ifplugd**. So I've created a policy:

```
module rpi-ifplugd 1.0.0;
require {
   type ifplugd_t;
   type udev_t;
   type ifplugd_exec_t;
   class process transition;
}
type_transition udev_t ifplugd_exec_t : process ifplugd_t;
```

And it worked!

```
$ ls -lZ /run/ifplugd.eth0.pid
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root system_u:object_r:ifplugd_var_run_t:s0 5 Sep  5 08:09 /run/ifplugd.eth0.pid
```

But I don't know if this decision is good. Please leave a comment.

Comment: I think this is a suitable question to SuperUser, not security. I am voting to move it there.

Comment: @ThoriumBR: Advanced questions regarding SELinux may also find a good place on [unix.se].